# How to format string using MessageFormat in JSTL

Tags: jsp, jstl, messageformat

A string is got from ENV variable by the following codes:

```
<span><%=(String)System.getenv("NEW_COPYRIGHT")%></span>
```

The ENV variable is like `Copyright &copy; {0} XXX`.

How to replace `{0}` with the current year and display `Copyright  © 2018 XXX` in the jsp file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard `jstl` tag to do this.We can use other way to do it.

a. Use `fn:replace` to do it:

```
<c:set var="env" value="Copyright &copy; {0} XXX"/>
<c:out value="${fn:repalce(env,'{0}','2018')}"/> <!-- the year can also be access via a variable -->
```

b. Define your own custom tag to format it using `java.text.MessageFormat`,more details can be found at **[Understanding and Creating Custom JSP Tags](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/taglib/quickstart.html)**